# Populate HTML table with MySQL data (multiple images for a table cell)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to populate `HTML` table with the data comes from my database. Here I have stored "services" in my table. Each service may have multiple images. So when populating the table it should have 3 table `cells` one for "service name" and second for "description" and third one for images.

This is my SQL query looks like:

```
$prep_stmt = " SELECT s.id
                    , s.name
                    , s.description
                    , i.image
                    , i.image_path
                FROM  services s
                LEFT JOIN images i ON i.service_id = s.id";
```

This is how my `while` look like this:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {        
    $html  = "<tr>\n";  
    $html .= "  <td><input type='checkbox'></td>\n";    
    $html .= "  <td>\n";    
    $html .= "      <a href='' class='name'>{$name}</a>\n";     
    $html .= "  </td>\n";   
    $html .= "  <td class='view_html'>{$description}</td>\n";   
    $html .= "  <td>\n";    
                --- My images should be display here ---- 
    $html .= "  </td>\n";   
    $html .= "</tr>\n";                 

    //Add output to array
    $output[] = $html;  
}
```

My problem is How I display multiple images in one table cell? If one service have only one image then I can do it, but it has multiple images then I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: first store those values in an array, then use that array for generating the html table

Comment: @FerozAkbar, Thank you for your comment. But I an not sure how to do it. Can you kindly show me with an example? Thank you.

Comment: I'd take out the join. Pull all services then query all images at the HTML creation when needed. As is you'll get multiple rows per ID, which I don't think you want.

Comment: If I understand what you are doing in the database, @chris85 is correct. Using a join here is just going to give you multiple lines for your services for each picture associated with the service. Using 2 queries will allow you to place multiple images in the final column for each service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your sql code as below and try

```
 $prep_stmt = " SELECT s.id
                    , s.name
                    , s.description
                    , (select group_concat(i.image_path,'/',i.image)  from images i where i.service_id = s.id) as img
                FROM  services s";
```

Then use this Html code

```
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {        
    $html  = "<tr>";  
    $html .= "  <td><input type='checkbox'></td>";    
    $html .= "  <td>";    
    $html .= "     <a href='' class='name'>{$name}</a>";     
    $html .= "  </td>";   
    $html .= "  <td class='view_html'>{$description}</td>";   

    $html .= "  <td>";
    $img_array=explode(",",$img);
    foreach($img_array as $im){
        if($im==''){
         $html .= " <img src='default.jpg'>";   
        }else{
         $html .= " <img src='{$im}'>";   
        }
    }
    $html .= "  </td>";

    $html .= "</tr>";                 

    //Add output to array
    $output[] = $html;  
}
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is cool. I didn't know you could return an array like that.

Comment: Changed sql query. Try again

Comment: Can you kindly explain updated mysql query and why it didn't work earlier one?

Comment: Previous sql that I updated; group all images thats why u got one row . But actually u want to get images that are associated with service ID.

Comment: @Sameeraa4ever, one more question. Is there way to display a default image if `$im` is null?